# tap method in Rails 3 - Have I understood the API Docs correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm upgrading a rails 2 application to rails 3.2 and have come across what is described as an idiom.

`person.tap |p| do`

When I Googled for this and [it appears to have been deprecated or moved](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/tap). Is my understanding correct?

I ask because I can find a few examples of it on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `tap` method has been in [Ruby since 1.8.7](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Object.html#method-i-tap):

> **tap{|x|...} => obj**
>
> Yields `x` to the block, and then returns `x`. The primary purpose of this method is to “tap into” a method chain, in order to perform operations on intermediate results within the chain.

Note that 1.8.6 did not have `Object#tap`. Presumably, `tap` was in older versions of Rails (as a monkey patch on `Object`) but was added to Ruby itself in 1.8.7. Since 1.8.6 is rather ancient now, the Rails version was deprecated and, in more recent Rails releases, removed entirely.

[`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-tap) is still around so `tap` itself has not been deprecated, just the Rails monkey patched version has been removed.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance as I learn the basics. I assume this means I can still use it. 
When you say "tap into" do you mean its like a 'glue' between methods when a method cannot be called directly?

Comment: @user1149642: yes, you can still use it. The docs I linked to have some examples.

Answer (score 4):

The `Object#tap` monkey patch from `ActiveSupport` is deprecated because it has been part of Ruby since 1.9.0 and 1.8.7.